# Shared Codebase for C#.NET and Xamarin Mobile apps?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm lead dev on a new project at work to build a combination web and mobile app for internal project management. The descriptor "internal project management" is generic and may mean different things to different people, so please don't focus too much on that. Most of our stuff is M$ and C# is the future (compared to my company's history with VB, VBA, VBS), so I'm thinking C# and Xamarin. Know any good literature on making the most of shared codebase for mobile/web with Xamarin/C#.NET?

To my knowledge, Xamarin does not support web app development, only "iOS, Android, and Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 8.1, and the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) for Windows 10". Unless we have a reliable timeline for the entire company upgrading to Windows 10 (we don't) we shouldn’t build in that direction. We can maintain two closely related codebases of C#.NET and Xamarin. The trick is how closely?

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend reading the new bits to .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library or https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md

Xamarin now supports .NET Standard:

https://blog.xamarin.com/net-standard-library-support-for-xamarin/

Because of this, you can leverage the use of .NET Standard as a `Shared` layer across your applications. You would then treat each stack (Web, Desktop, Mobile, etc) as a platform specific stack that you would implement native features/UI/etc into. However you can completely leverage all of your shared code via the standard library.

This is a common question answered in the FAQ here:

https://www.xamarin.com/faq#q2

Or expanded upon via our documentation:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/ (**Note: This will be expanded in the future to include .NET Standard)**

Comment: Can you update your answer, please? All Xamarin links are redirecting to Microsoft website and they no longer have the information you posted.